# date format in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

how to get records between current date to next 30 days in laravel 5?
Here is the code i used for that.

```
public static function getNextInspections() 
{
$inspection = DB::table('inspection');
$inspection->select('*');
$inspection ->where('next_inspection_date', DB::raw('BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)'));
return $inspection->get();
```

}

I don't get proper answer in laravel 5. 
but I got the answer in mysql. Given below is the MySQL command i used:

"select equipment_id, next_inspection_date,deleted_at from inspection where next_inspection_date BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);"

Can anyone help me with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$inspection ->whereBetween('next_inspection_date ', array(Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()->addMonth(1)));
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your prompt reply. Actually I used this one too. but not getting the proper results.

Answer (score 0):

After Laravel 5.5 you can use now() function to get the current date and time.

You can write a query as below.

```
$inspection ->whereBetween('next_inspection_date ', array(now(), now()->addMonth(1)));
```

[image]